# Entry Widget is driving me nuts!: Tkinter Reddit Scraper thinks that a string entry is numbers?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, reddit, scraper

Im in the middle of a small project, to create a tkinter gui that outputs the top ten posts from a user-defined subreddit from reddit.com using their api. Because I need to have the subreddit be the choice of the user, it needs to be inputted using a tkinter entry widget. However, the problem i'm having is that the widget does not refresh when the user puts in information, and instead it just outputs a bunch of numbers (".4302552760.4302552816.4367528344") right when the program launches. I can't seem to get this thing to just record what the user puts in as a string variable so I can run that through the next few classes and make the damn thing work. Ive hit a real roadblock here, and would really appreciate some help.

Ill give a few samples of the code, the whole thing, and then the specific problem areas:

The whole code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from webbrowser import open
from datetime import date
import praw


'''Initialising the Applicaiton'''
class RedditScraper(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, redditReturn):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

'''The First Page the User will see'''
class StartPage(tk.Frame, object):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        '''label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Confirm This Subreddit", command= confirmSubreddit())
        label2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)'''

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Scrape This Subreddit", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(redditReturn))
        button1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        e1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        StartPage.entry1 = e1



'''Adding brackets around the user's entry to the label to suffice the praw api'''      
class bracketEntry(object):
    def addBrackets(self):
        user_entry_plus_brackets = '"' + str(StartPage.entry1) + '"'
        print(user_entry_plus_brackets)
        return user_entry_plus_brackets


'''Collecting data from reddit'''
class redditCollect(object):

    def getSubreddit(self):
        user_agent = "Simple Subreddit Scraper"
        r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)
        '''remember to add the ability to get the user-defined subreddit information'''
        user_entry = bracketEntry()
        user_entry_variable = user_entry.addBrackets()
        posts = r.get_subreddit("pics").get_hot(limit = 10)
        return posts



'''The window containing the information from Reddit for the user'''        
class redditReturn(tk.Frame, object):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        """Creates all the buttons and frames for the GUI"""
        get_user_entry = bracketEntry()
        get_user_entry_string = get_user_entry.addBrackets()

        intro = get_user_entry_string + " on Reddit: "
        newFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text = intro)
        newFrame.pack(fill="both", expand= True , anchor="nw")        
        row = 0
        redditCollectGetter = redditCollect()
        local_posts = redditCollectGetter.getSubreddit()
        for p in local_posts:
            gotoArticle = partial(open, p.url)
            title = "(" + str(p.score) +") " + p.title
            tk.Label(newFrame, text= title, pady= 10, wraplength= 700, justify= "left").grid(row= row, column= 0, sticky= "w")
            tk.Button(newFrame, text= "Read more!", command= gotoArticle).grid(row= row+1, column= 0, sticky= "w")
            tk.row = row + 2




app = RedditScraper()
app.mainloop()
```

Here is the class where I defined the entry widget (if this helps at all):

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame, object):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        '''label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Confirm This Subreddit", command= confirmSubreddit())
        label2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)'''

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Scrape This Subreddit", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(redditReturn))
        button1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        e1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        StartPage.entry1 = e1
```

Here is where I am first trying to manipulate the entry to add parenthesis around it so it can work with the reddit api:

```
class bracketEntry(object):
    def addBrackets(self):
        user_entry_plus_brackets = '"' + str(StartPage.entry1) + '"'
        print(user_entry_plus_brackets)
        return user_entry_plus_brackets
```

I put print(user_entry_plus_brackets) here to show that it is outputting a bunch of numbers instead of the string that the user enters.

I am extremely new to python (and coding in general) and perhaps have gone over my head... Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about widgets is that when you coerce them to a string, they return their tkinter id.  What you need to do is create a control variable (http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) and associate it with your entry.

```
self.entry_var = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entry_var)
```

Instead of retrieving the value from the entry as you are doing:

```
str(StartPage.entry1)
```

you get the value of the control variable like this:

```
user_entry_plus_brackets = '"' + self.entry_var.get() + '"'
```

I'm not at home right now where I could test this out, but I believe that you should be able to get the value of the Entry using it's .get() method without needing to use a control variable:

```
user_entry_plus_brackets = '"' + self.entry1.get() + '"'
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't _need_ a control variable for this. It's one solution but it's not the only solution. Your last paragraph is correct, you can use the `get()` method without adding an additional control variable.

Comment: Hi Bryan, my code is now outputting an error of:    TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'controller'    I have no clue how to fix this, and it had never appeared before, do you have an answer? Thanks!